# dataframe split or reframe in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with only two columns. The first column is a bunch of numeric values and the second column is numbers 1-6 (essentially six different classes). I want to convert the data frame into where there are six columns each with their corresponding values. the column headers should be labeled 1-6. How do I do this in R? Should I use split, dplyr or is there another way?

dataframe looks something like this:

```
prob class
 37.  1.  
 23.  5        
 23   5              
 76.  6
```

and I want something like this:

`1   2   3.  4.  5.  6

37. 45. 12. 25  23  76
            `

Comment: This is a job for something like `tidyr`'s `pivot_wider`.

Comment: Have you tried solution posted in this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: yes i tried that thread and nothing worked

Comment: Can you add data in a reproducible format? something which we can copy/paste into R and use. Read about how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)